# Входная строка имела неверный формат C#

Tags: c#

Вот код

```
List<int> TextElements= null;
for (int i = 0; i < CoutOfElements(); i++)
TextElements.Add(Convert.ToInt32(GetText(i).Substring(1,GetText(i).Length-1)));
```

где `GetText(i)` = -40%

Выдаёт ошибку "входная строка имела неверный формат"

Comment: Так может покажете что за `GetText()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В результате выполнения:
    GetText(i).Substring(1,GetText(i).Length-1)

результат "40%", а не "40". Надо изменить на Length-2

```
List<int> TextElements= null;
for (int i = 0; i < CoutOfElements(); i++)
     TextElements.Add(Convert.ToInt32(GetText(i).Substring(1,GetText(i).Length-2)));
```

Учитесь пользоваться отладчиком.

Comment: Было бы, вообще говоря, неплохо, чтобы на момент добавления числа в список этот самый список не был равен `null`.

Comment: Согласен с Вами))

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего то, что получается в результате манипуляции со строкой - это не число => `Convert.ToInt32` выдает данное исключение. За подробностями обращайтесь к отладчику и смотрите, что возвращается.